# Convert T01D163DE49AED860 to a datetime?

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime, ms-word, office-interop

In Word MRU list in Registry, it seems like the datetime is stored like `T01D163DE49AED860`.

Any idea how I convert this to a datetime?

Comment: And what should be the result exactly as a `DateTime`? I didn't this format before.

Comment: It's 10th of feburary 2016 09:37.

Comment: Where is this registry exactly? Can you please show it's location?

Comment: There is an explanation of format here pp8-9: [Microsoft Office 2007, 2010 – Registry Artifacts](https://ad-pdf.s3.amazonaws.com/Microsoft_Office_2007-2010_Registry_ArtifactsFINAL.pdf). The tool is here (could be used to verify your code): [DCode](http://www.digital-detective.net/digital-forensic-software/free-tools/)

Comment: I added as a C# solution as well. Check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a Hex registry value. The key is located here:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsBackup\Status

```
Dim regTime As Long = CLng(Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey( _
    "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsBackup\Status").GetValue( _
    "LastSuccess"))
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(regTime)
Me.Text = dt.ToLocalTime.ToString
```

Comment: Hmmm don't think so, because I get this error... DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc("T01D163DE49AED860")' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException

Comment: @MojoDK Of course, you need to get convert the string (without the initial T) to a numeric (long) value first. Which is what the Registry call in the answer does.

Comment: Ah ok thanks ... this worked ... DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc("&H01D163DE49AED860")

Comment: @MojoDK How? o.O `FromFileTimeUtc` does not _even_ has an overload takes `string` as a parameter.

Comment: My bad ... DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(CLng("&H01D163DE49AED860")) :)

Comment: I don't care if it's VB og C#. I work both in VB and C# - for this project it's VB. My main issue was the date format, not if it's VB og C#.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already read that `T01D163DE49AED860` as a `string` with [`Registry.GetValue` metho](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue)d or something, looks like first `T` character is pointing this is a time value and rest of it is hexadecimal value that you can parse to `long` first.

Delete the first `T` character of your string, parse it to `long` with [`AllowHexSpecifier` style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles) and use [`FromFileTimeUtc` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletimeutc) to get your `DateTime`.

```
var s = "T01D163DE49AED860";
s = s.Remove(0, 1);
long long1 = long.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
var dt = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(long1);
```

But this returns `10.02.2016 08:37:34`, if your current timezone is `UTC +01:00` right now, you can use [`ToLocalTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime) to get `10.02.2016 09:37:34` like;

```
var dt = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(long1).ToLocalTime();
```